# Obtaining values from objects

Tags: array, oop

This code works fine and returns two StdClass Objects for each of my two posts:

```
        $children = get_pages($args);

        foreach ($children as $cake=>$element) {
            $args = array(
                          'post_id' => $ID
                          );
            $Comments = get_comments( $args );
        };
```

This is great. I get each comment's properties but I am only interested in the comment date. My desired output is:

$CommentDates = (date1, date2, etc) -- Eventually I'd like to get the most recent comment date.

My next move is:

```
        foreach ($Comments as $CommentObject) {
            $CommentDates = $CommentObject->comment_date;
        }
```

This returns only one date and it happens to be the second object's value.

However, if I simply echo this foreach, I get both dates.

foreach ($Comments as $CommentObject) {
                echo $CommentObject->comment_date;
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your use of `foreach` (in both cases) is that you are erasing any previous value `$Comments` or `$CommentDates` had before the current iteration. Rather than setting the value to the variable itself, perhaps you should be appending new values onto the variable as an array:

```
// Not sure what purpose your $cake and $element serve here )
foreach( $children as $cake => $element ) {
  $args = array( 'post_id' => $ID ); // Assuming this $ID is declared elsewhere
  $comments[] = get_comments( $args );
}

foreach( $comments as $commentObject ) {
  $commentDates[] = $commentObject->comment_date;
}
```

Of course, these two `foreach` statements could be blended into one single `foreach` unless details not specified in your question would prevent that.

This would result in two arrays: `$comments` containing all of the results from each iterative call to `get_comments()`, and `$commentsDates` containing the iterative results to each `$commentObject` on its `comment_date` property.

Comment: This will throw an 'undefined variable' notice - the `$commentDates` array should be declared before the loop.

Comment: However, if they're not, they will be created for you. Though for cleanliness, I agree that it is best to have them defined. That being said, I cannot commit myself to cleaning up the OP's code more than is necessary.

Comment: Double brackets are key!

Answer (score 1):

```
$CommentDates = array();
foreach ( $Comments as $Comment ) {
    $CommentDates[] = $Comment->comment_date;
}
```

will save the dates into an array.

```
$CommentDates = '';
$length = count( $Comments );
for ( $i = 0, $i < $length, $++ ) {
    $CommentDates .= $Comment->comment_date;
    if ( ! $i == ( $length - 1 ) ) {
        $CommentDates .= ', ';
    }
}
```

will create a string in the format you proposed in the question.

Resources:

- [php: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [php: Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)